# JDBC: Connect to MS SQL DB via SSL from Linux machine

Tags: sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL database via SSL from Linux machine with the following url: `jdbc:sqlserver://server.com\TEST;database=test_db;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true`, java 8, ms-sql driver 7.2.1.0, JDBC4.2.

Got this error: `[08S01] This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:2580b81c-d9de-4394-89e8-826ea0e0c343`

All the solutions leads to `sqljdbc_auth.dll` which doesn't work on Linux machine. Is there any way to solve the issue with Linux machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either connect using SQL Server Auth, passing a user name and password in the connection url, as per:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-2017

Or configure Kerberos:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks. But we can't use Kerberos for some reasons. Tried first solution and got this error: Connection to 1C-OFRIK-GT failed.
[08S01] The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:1060aafa-5ed8-4558-97f5-016551de820c

Comment: Also tried to use integratedSecurity=false param. And connections works. But did ssl connection used in this case?

Comment: SSL and Integrated Authentication are completely unrelated.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017